# How to split and access time in individual digits? [hh:mm:ss]

Tags: python, loops, time, while-loop, timecodes

I want to split the time into individual digits.
For Eg. We usually look at time in `HH: MM: SS`

- I want to break it down and access both the H, M, and S separately. Like HH should be accessible as H1 [the first digit] and H2 [the second digit] and so on for minutes and seconds.
- Please note I am looking for real-time values of the broken variables.

Comment: Hi, Can you be more precise ? What time do you want ? The current time ? Some `datetime` variable ?

Comment: What exactly is "the time" you want to do this for?  And how does "real-time" affect anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible like this:

```
from datetime import datetime


# We get the current time.
d = datetime.now()
time_now = d.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("time:", time_now)

# We divide the received time into elements.
time_split = [int(t) for t in time_now if t != ":"]
print(time_split)
```

```
time: 17:08:39
[1, 7, 0, 8, 3, 9]
```

Where H1= time_split[0] etc.
Or you can create a dictionary with the variables you need:

```
var_list = ("h1", "h2", "", "m1", "m2", "", "s1", "s2")
time_dict = {v: int(t) for v, t in zip(var_list, time_now) if t != ":"}
print(time_dict)

{'h1': 1, 'h2': 7, 'm1': 0, 'm2': 8, 's1': 3, 's2': 9}
```